# How do I reset the tick function in my pomodoro timer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer

I am working on a Pomodoro style timer in ReactJS. I have the code written out for the work timer and break timer, however once the break timer gets to 0, it automatically starts the work timer again. How do I get the process to reset and to let the user click start again to get the work timer going. Below is the code for the `tick()` function I have, but it's still starting over after the break once the break timer finishes. Not sure what I am doing wrong, any help appreciated!

```
  tick() {
    const timerType = this.state.workTimer ? "work" : "break";
    if(this.state[timerType+"Time"]*60 - Math.round(this.state.elapsed / 1000) <= 0) {
      clearInterval(this.ticker);
      this.setState({
        workTimer: !this.state.workTimer,
        startTime: new Date()
      });
      this.ticker = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
    }
    this.setState({
      elapsed: new Date() - this.state.startTime
    });
    if(this.state[timerType+"break"]*60 - Math.round(this.state.elapsed / 1000) <= 0) {
      clearInterval(this.ticker);
      this.setState({
        elapsed: null
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

look like your first if condition start timer again after break. You can add workTimer check in first if statmen, e.g.

```
if(this.state[timerType+"Time"]*60 - Math.round(this.state.elapsed / 1000) <= 0 && this.state.workTimer) {}
```